# Написание и склонение названия университета Карнеги-Меллон

Tags: склонение, тире, дефис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, склоняются ли фамилии в названии университета Карнеги-Меллон (в университете Карнеги-Меллон). И ставится ли между фамилиями дефис или тире? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Так как в названии использованы фамилии двух людей (а не двойная фамилия), дефис исключается, а ставится тире - как, например, у [закона Бойля — Мариотта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8F_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0).

[Университет Карнеги — Меллона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Склоняется вторая фамилия - по правилам склонения иноязычных фамилий на согласный.

*В университете Карнеги — Меллона.*

Comment: Розенталь это подтвердил бы: _Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими именами собственными, совокупностью которых называется какое-либо учение, **научное учреждение** и т. п._ http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=312

Comment: а слово "университет" не должно быть с прописной? "В Университете Карнеги — Меллона"? Это ведь официальное название учреждения.

Comment: Нет, а с чего бы? https://www.classicalmusicnews.ru/articles/how-to-write-philharmonia/

Comment: В оригинале заведение называется Carnegie Mellon University.

Comment: А как расставлять пробелы в составных названиях вокруг тире и в двойных фамилиях вокруг дефиса? Одни корректоры издательств требует вокруг тире вставлять шпации по 2 пункта, другие говорят, что пробелы вообще не нужны. Кто прав? Вокруг дефиса пробелы вроде бы не ставят.

Comment: Из Справки Грамоты.ру: ***Пишется тире с пробелами: закон Бойля – Мариотта. Между двумя разными фамилиями ставится тире; дефис же пишется между частями одной фамилии, например: картина Петрова-Водкина; Единственный случай, когда тире не отбивается пробелами, – позиция между цифрами: "Многие его стихотво­рения этого периода (1560–1562) содержат философские и политические мотивы".*** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2